# Application Loader is showing older icon

Tags: ios, xcode, application-loader

I'm trying to submit a newer version 2.0 of my app to the App Store. I cleaned and archived the "product", then exported it and opened it with the Application Loader but it is showing the icon of the version 1.0.

Any suggestions? Is there a "deeper cleaning" option? Should I just submit it hoping it will resolve itself in the end? I triple checked the images and everything is in its place.

Answer (score 1):

The same your question describes happened to me.

What I did was to continue the upload process normally and it uploaded correctly, with the new icon.

So you just have to upload your app normally, when it processes it will be with your new icon!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Have a look here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1686/_index.html

Make sure you don't have any version of the old icon in the app. If you do have a version of the old icon anywhere in the project, make sure it isn't named in one of the names listed under the "File Name" section in the above link. Application loader (and AppStore) might use it instead of the new icon.

Comment: I have changed the name of all icons in the assets and made sure there is no accessible trace of the older icon in the system. I selected the app.ipa file from Application Loader > Choose and not only the icon stays the same as the older one but the "display name" still hasn't changed.

Comment: Could it be that it just downloads the older app icon and display name from the app store servers? I'm not trying to submit it from the Xcode I'm only trying to upload the .ipa file for review. The app store servers still have the older icon and display name which will change when the app is approved.